# Select Drop down coming over bootstrap nav drop down for hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a select drop-down and one is bootstrap navigation drop-down, instead of click to open bootstrap navigation drop-down I changed it on mouse over but when the select drop-down is open and mouse over on bootstrap navigation drop-down its going behind select dropdown

[image: See image]

Comment: You need to check the z-index on the nav hover menu. Could you post a working code of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.navbar-drop-down {
    z-index: 2; # Or higher
}
```